# How does windows encodes non English path?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, path, pgadmin

When providing a Filename of `C:\א\Toc1.dump` to the [pgadmin's](https://www.pgadmin.org/) backup tool, it reproduces behind the scene an encoded path of `C:\\0F04~1\\TOC1.DUMP` as in the screen shot:

[image]

When I trigger the `pg_dump.exe` from windows cmd or PowerShell it always fail when referring it with the non-English character path:

```
pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\א\\TOC1.DUMP" ... Not Working!
```

The pg_dump tool tells it can't find the path:

> pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not open input file "..."

But when I trigger the exe with the encoded path it works OK:

```
pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\0F04~1\\TOC1.DUMP" ... //--WORKS!!
```

So I trying to make it work from code and I need to figure out how to properly encode the path when passing the args to the pg_dump.exe.

My question: **How does windows encodes the path**? How did it came up with `0F04~1` from `א`?

---

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70567560/6844481), I was told that `pgadmin` does not do the encoding by itself, and that is it something that being held by windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both. It would appear that the tool you’re using does not use Unicode-capable Windows APIs. The path that does work is the 8.3 path. It is created for compatibility with DOS applications that do not support long file names.

You can see it using `dir /x`:

```
05.01.2022  19:51    <DIR>          0F04~1       א
```

(Note that א displays as an box with a question mark in it in Command Prompt.)

Whether 8.3 name creation is enabled is a per-volume property. It is enabled by default on the system volume.

---

Because backslash is the path separator in Windows, it is *not* an escape character and does not need to be duplicated like you did. This applies to both Command Prompt and PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, could you please the centence Using dir /x ? Where is it written?

Comment: wondering if launching `cmd` using `/U` option would affect the behavior ( https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html )

Comment: @ShaharShokrani If you're looking for information about `dir`, it has a built-in help function: `dir /?` If you wanted something different, please clarify.

Comment: @Yorik No, the problem is with the default(?) font _Consolas_. It simply does not have the required glyphs.