# How to apply Windows short path (8.3) to network path?

Tags: windows, networking, path, .net-framework

Following my question [here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1697642/1498638) and [here on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70567560/6844481).

I've noticed that [Windows 8.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) path only apply to local path like: `C:\Program Files` and not on network path like: `\\MyNetworkPAth\Shared folder\MyFooFolder` (it returns the same path).

For example decoding Windows 8.3 path of `C:\Program Files` with using the .NET code of:

```
public static extern int GetShortPathName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string path, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder shortPath, int shortPathLength);

StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(248);
GetShortPathName("C:\Program Files", shortPath, shortPath.Capacity);
string destinationPath = shortPath.ToString(); --> "C:\PROGRA~1"
```

While network path:

```
StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(248);
GetShortPathName("\\MyNetworkPAth\Shared folder\MyFooFolder", shortPath, shortPath.Capacity);
string destinationPath = shortPath.ToString(); --> "\\MyNetworkPAth\Shared folder\MyFooFolder"
```

Is it possible to apply Windows 8.3 path to network paths?

Comment: Windows 8.3 paths can only be retrieved if they are there. You can use cmd with `dir /x` to see them, but indeed, on network shares, they are empty, so long answer short, not possible, only locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ability to apply `8dot3` names on file system depend on the following subjects:

1. The specific path should be related to a volume. Only if the specific path is “located” on a volume this volume can be configured to support the `8dot3` names.
2. The specific path should be related to a volume that configured to support `8dot3` names.

To understand more deeply how it works and how to configure volume to support  `8dot3` names see the [`fsutil 8dot3name`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name) command description.

To list all volumes on a system use the `diskpart` command:

- <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- `diskpart` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `list volume` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The displayed list of volumes can help to understand if the specific path can be converted to the `8dot3` format.

Additional references:
[Naming a Volume](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-volume)